# Is iptables enough security, if port 80 is the only unblocked port and apache is setup correctly?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, php, svn

We are using PHP,MySQL,SVN, and Apache. I want to know if I assume the local subnet trusted, and allow all ports on our subnet using iptables, then allow only port 80 as open to "anyone". If it is "good security" taking that the subnet is trusted as a premise. This is also assuming good PHP code etc, and that apache is configured correctly.

This is using CentOS 5.